# does it make sense to use shareReplay where i want to replay the value but do not want it to share with multiple observer

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have one scenario where I need to fetch the mapping for status and priority from backend, as it is static values so once the application loads I do not want to get those values multiple time from backend so for that I need a way which can give me values again without calling the backend here is the snippet for that which I am using.

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        const status  = this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darpankumar/Fakedb/status').pipe(
          shareReplay(1)
        );

        const priority = this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darpankumar/Fakedb/priority').pipe(
          shareReplay(1)
       );
        this.statusPriority$ = combineLatest(status,priority)
      }
```

and the place where I need to use it I use it like this

```js
    btnClick() {
        this.task$ = this.statusPriority$.pipe(flatMap((data :Array<any>) => {
          const [status, priority] = [...data];
          return this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darpankumar/Fakedb/data').pipe(
          map((data : any) =>{
            // this is the place where i do the mapping. 
            data.status = status[data.statusCode];
            data.priority = priority[data.priorityCode];
            return data;
          })
        );
        }))  
      }
```

So my question in brief is, is it a right way to implement this behaviour, as one thing which is bothering me is `shareReplay` gives a `multicast observable` and I am not using it multiple places.

but apart from this, I can not find any way which can achieve the same functionality for me.

And another question is is there any way I can make this status and priority observable hot so that it fetches the values on load time, not on the button click.

I know I can use `behavioursubject(withsomeinitialValue)` and then can do the backend call and subscribe to those values in ts and can do the next on behavioursubject but i do not want to do the subscription in the component.

[fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdehhl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem, short answers, it's ok. I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve the same behavior in another way without using Subjects while keeping the `status` and `priority` as observables.

Why is it ok, if you use a multicast observable with a single subscriber it is the same as using unicast observable. You can picture it as

```js
let unicast = (x) => x

unicast('something')

let multicast = [(x)=>x]

multicast.map(fn => fn('something'))
```

so there isn't that much of a difference.

Anyways my approach will be a bit different for this problem, I will create some kind of service and inside of it will do the following

```js
...
loadStaticVariables(){
const status  = this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darpankumar/Fakedb/status');

const priority = this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darpankumar/Fakedb/priority');

combineLatest(status,priority)
.subscribe(staticValueFromTheserver =>{
this.statusPriority = staticValueFromTheserver;
})
}
```

(And of course, this function should be called at some point before showing the button)

And after that, I would use the variable wherever I need.

#### Pros

- On load of the app you will get this static values (Which solves your problem)

#### Cons

- I don't find such

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i could see one thing which i want to avoid is subscribing in the service, it reminds me of the imperative programming.

Answer (score 1):

> And another question is is there any way I can make this status and priority observable hot so that it fetches the values on load time, not on the button click.

I think there is a way. You can use any of the `publish*` operators, because they return a `ConnectableObservable`, which has a `connect()` method that will allow you to subscribe to the source.

```js
const status$  = this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darpankumar/Fakedb/status');

const priority$ = this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/darpankumar/Fakedb/priority');

const connectableObs = combineLatest(status$,priority$).pipe(
  publishReplay(1),
) as ConnectableObservable<any>;

this.statusPriority$ = connectableObs;

// Load data on load times
// You can add it to an `ngOnInit` hook or in a service's constructor
this.subscription = connectableObs.connect();
```

And then you can `statusPriority$` the same way as you did before.

`connectableObs.connect()` will subscribe to the source; in this case, it will get the data from those endpoints. Because you're using `publishReplay`, there will be a `ReplaySubject` which will get the data from the source and when a new subscriber is registered(e.g in `btnClick`), that subscriber will get the data cached by the subject.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what you think about this approach, both publishreplay and shareReplay gives multicast observable. is this a right way to acheive this functionality ? As i can not find any way which is unicast and can be replayed.

Comment: IMO, I don't have any problem with this. As far as I understood, you have only one subscriber, but that subscriber will be re-subscribed multiple times, so you wouldn't want to make an API call for each subscription. You could for sure use this approach, it's the same as _manually_ using a `ReplaySubject`, but this approach involves less lines of code. It's true that it becomes multicast, but you can also create a cache with minimum efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, you are a weekend saver :)

Comment: It was my pleasure to help! Thank you. Good luck!